# How can I implement an intermediary step in between two signers?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following workflow:

1. Send envelope request
2. First user signs.
3. First user must do some action on local system.
4. Once user has done that action, THEN the next signer in the routing order is notified to sign.

Is there a way to use the API to put an intermediary task in between the two signers so the second signer isn't emailed until the middle task is done?  Could I create an intermediary or approver where I could use the API to tell docusign that the task is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two techniques that can be used to pause the routing of an envelope.

### Fake Embedded Signer (Envelope created via the API)

If the envelope is being **created** via the API, then a "fake" embedded signer can be added with a routing order to stop the processing when it is the fake embedded signer's turn to sign. For example, use routing order:

1. Real signer 1
2. Fake embedded signer
3. Real signer 2
4. Real cc recipient

Then use Connect or eventNotification so your app is notified after Real Signer 1 has completed (signed) the envelope. Now your app can do the external work.

When you're ready for the envelope's routing to proceed, delete the fake recipient via the [EnvelopeRecipients::delete](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/delete/) method.

### Fake Certified Delivery Recipient (Envelope created via web tool or template)

If the envelope will be created via template or from the DocuSign web tool, then you can't easily include an embedded signer. Instead, use a fake [Certified Delivery recipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients#certified-deliveries-recipient).

To avoid any email bounce back issues, you must specify an email address that exists but which is actually a *[blackhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_(networking)#Black_hole_e-mail_addresses)* -- no one should have access to the emails.

When the routing order reaches the fake certified delivery recipient, routing will stop since no one will respond to the email from DocuSign confirming the delivery of the envelope.

Same as above, your application can be notified about the envelope by Connect or eventNotification. Your application can perform its processing and then restart routing, same as above, by deleting the fake recipient from the envelope.

Also, note that you can include Envelope Custom Fields to provide additional processing configuration options--the Envelope Custom Fields can be set by the sender via the DocuSign web tool and then read by your application program.

Comment: The fake embedded signer way should work for me.  I'll wait a bit more to see if there are any more official, less hacky solutions, but this may be the accepted answer.  Thanks Larry.

Comment: I contacted DocuSign support and they confirmed this was the way to do what I wanted.  Thank you again Larry.